# Handling errors from an array input field from Laravel with VuejS

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, error-handling

I've been trying to work with Laravel and VueJS in a project.

In one of my inputs I have an array input for a set of roles and requirements required for a job posting. This is how it looks like in the request form:

```
 public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'roles_and_responsibilities'   => ['required'], 
            'roles_and_responsibilities.*' => ['required'], 
        ];
    }
```

However, I am trying to get the validation errors for these in my VueJS using Axios' catch method. I would then get the error message, assign it to a variable and then just output it on the template, the way I do it is as follows.

```
  .catch((err) => {
                err.response.data.errors.title ? errors.title = err.response.data.errors.title[0] : ''
  }
```

I am just having a problem trying to output the one from the array field validation since it is sent back like this in the response

```
 "roles_and_responsibilities.0": [
            "The roles_and_responsibilities.0 field is required."
        ],
```

I cannot really do **err.response.data.errors.roles_and_responsibilities.0[0]** since it would give me an error for the `.0`.

Any help is well appreciated!

I tried using concat to attach the `.0[0]` but did not work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use bracket notation `title['prop.0']` like you are accessing an array. this is what the results will be returned from Laravel because js doesn't have multidimensional arrays. however, this is the work around.

Comment: I just tried this and it worked! Thank you. What I did was err.response.data.errors.['roles_and_responsibilities.0']. However to access the actual message I had to assign it to  a variable then call it there like this data[0]. Thank you for the help!